# Get functions docstring/inital comment [Python]

Tags: python, frameworks, bots

So I recently ran into a framework (for a chat bot) that was very clever.

It used a combination of things to make it extremely dynamic. Most of these things I already know how to replicate. Yet there was something that really caught my eye, and made me really wonder.

**How do you obtain the comment?**

```
def foo():
  '''My function comment'''
  return 'foo!'
```

**In this framework:** It would pull the comment, and use it as it's help.

So for example we say `!help foo`

It would return `My function comment`

It really boggles my mind, since I always thought comments weren't kept in memory. So I have to assume it's using some kind of inspection on it's own file. I'm just very curious on how this works, and if anyone has any libraries that would help with this, please let me know.

Edit: for anyone wanting to look at the framework; here is the [link](https://github.com/Twentysix26/Red-DiscordBot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a comment - comments are lines that start with `#`
This is a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

You can access the docstring using `foo.__doc__`

The help function would thus be

```
def help(thing)
    return thing.__doc__
```

When you type `!help foo` behind the scenes the framework calls `help(foo)`.

Comment: Worth noting that OP is confusing this for a comment, which it isn't; the docstring is a specific piece of Python syntax.

Comment: please accept the answer if it gives you the information you need

Answer (score 0):

You can access it with `.__doc__`